# returning an error while connecting snowflake to PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect snowflake database to PySpark. But it's returning an error. Below is the code

```
import snowflake.connector
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_last_result_spark():
    # get result of the last sql query 
    return spark.createDataFrame(cs.fetchall(), [x[0] for x in cs.description])

with open("key.p8", "rb") as key:   ##Read Note: Point num 2
    p_key= serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    key.read(),
    password=None,
    backend=default_backend())

pkb = p_key.private_bytes(
encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER,
format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption())

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=''    
    ,account=''
    ,authenticator=''
    ,private_key=pkb
    ,role=''
    ,warehouse=''
    ,database=''
    ,schema=''
)

cs = ctx.cursor()

submit_query_spark('select * from table limit 3;')

df = display(get_last_result_spark())
# ctx.close()
df
```

It's returning an error as below

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

<timed exec> in get_last_result_spark()

/projects/fmcganalytics/jupyter/conda/envs/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    673             return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(
    674                 data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
--> 675         return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    676 
    677     def _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema):

/projects/fmcganalytics/jupyter/conda/envs/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py in _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    698             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    699         else:
--> 700             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    701         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    702         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

/projects/fmcganalytics/jupyter/conda/envs/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    510 
    511         if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
--> 512             struct = self._inferSchemaFromList(data, names=schema)
    513             converter = _create_converter(struct)
    514             data = map(converter, data)

/projects/fmcganalytics/jupyter/conda/envs/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py in _inferSchemaFromList(self, data, names)
    439         schema = reduce(_merge_type, (_infer_schema(row, names) for row in data))
    440         if _has_nulltype(schema):
--> 441             raise ValueError("Some of types cannot be determined after inferring")
    442         return schema
    443 

ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring
```

Can anyone let me know why it's returning an issue. It's working well i wrote code for pandas. But for PySpark it's returning an issue. Can anyone please look into this issue?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use Snowflake Python connector rather than [Spark connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector.html)? Spark connector is the one to be used when using Spark.

Comment: Actually i tried with pandas first, then i'm trying with spark code.

Comment: Use Spark connector, it works with both Scala and PySpark code.

Comment: Do you reference or articles with you on that?

Comment: For using the Spark connector with Python? Like this oficial [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#using-the-connector-with-python) or you need something more specific?